# Camera Preview With Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-camera, surfaceview, zxing

I'm trying to implement an activity with action bar support that shows up a camera preview surface in **portrait** mode. I'm calculating best preview size (from zxing code), but that code is not considering action bar dimensions (i.e. height), returning stretched image preview. Anyone encountered similar problem before? Any tutorial out there, about opening camera preview considering action bar height?

EDIT:
I'm targetting API level >= 8.

1. I've added the style:

   true
       @null
       true

I didn't find any compatible name for android:windowActionModeOverlay, maybe no
support for that? What's the downside of not "overriding" it?

1. I had to add:

   android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

to FrameLayout, this way, I've the correct space between AB and layout, vertically.
I'm almost there, but **notification bar** is disappearing (I've only AB), I think because
of the full screen tag. I'm already satisfied with current result, but if people out
there have suggestions, they're welcome. =)

Answer (score 1):

You want the `SurfaceView` to remain the full size of the screen. The camera's preview resolutions mostly match the screen's aspect ratio, so if you don't, the device is forced to squash the image in one dimension a bit to fit it onto the view.

This means that you don't want the `ActionBar` to displace the main `SurfaceView`, but to sit on top of it. I make it transparent too. Here's the effect in action (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android):

[image]

Most of this is done by styling the `ActionBar` in your theme. Here's what I did to modify the default Holo theme to this end:

```
<style name="CaptureTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, really. I was in a hurry and I forgot few things about my aim. I've edited my question.